# 'make_pair' cannot be used as a function

Tags: c++, c++14, std-pair

This is my complete code:

```
  #include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <bits/stdc++.h> 

using namespace std;
#define ff first
#define mp make_pair

#define ss second


int main(void) {

    int m;
    vector <string> grid;

    cin >> m;

    pair <int,int> foo;
 pair <int,int> bar;


// bar =make_pair (10.5,'A');
foo = make_pair (1,2);
cout<<foo.ss<<endl;
    for(int i=0; i<m; i++) {
        string s; cin >> s;
        grid.push_back(s);
        int pp = s.find('p');
        int mp = s.find('m');
        if(pp>=0){
          bar = make_pair(pp,i);
        }
      cout<<pp<<endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

This is my error:

```
prog.cpp: In function 'int main()':
prog.cpp:40:32: error: 'make_pair' cannot be used as a function
            bar = make_pair(pp,i);
                                ^
```

`make_pair` gives this error when I placed it inside the for loop, it works completely fine if I place it out. Where am I going wrong?

Edit: I amtrying in codechef ide...these are the inputs

```
3
---
-m-
p--
```

Comment: Didn't you just ask this? You could have just edited and reopened your question.

Comment: [Cannot reproduce](http://ideone.com/9DkTbA)

Comment: @KerrekSB Can you check once again?

Comment: Sorry for deleting, I thought the question would be removed looking at the amount of downvotes.

Comment: Well, if you fix the question, there's a good chance people will undownvote...

Comment: Hey, that's what we call a "moving goalpost" question... best not to do that, people may rapidly feel that you're wasting their attention.

Comment: Yeah, I stopped reading at `#define ff first`

Comment: isn't macro definition a good practice,I have seen these a lot in coding contests, so I have been using it.

Comment: @MrRobot9 Doesn't the very existence of this question answer that one?

Comment: Yeah, I'm sorry about that.. wont happen again.

Comment: "isn't macro definition a good practice" -- No. In C? Maybe, sometimes, it depends. In C++? Almost never. "I have seen these a lot in coding contests, so I have been using it." -- What was the goal of those coding contests? It probably wasn't to create readable re-usable code.

Comment: Yeah, Thanks for correcting me. I will edit the question

Comment: Is this fine ??

Comment: Please don't fix code in your question after the issues have been pointed out.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> ```
> #define mp make_pair
> ...
>     int mp = s.find('m');
> ...
>       bar = make_pair(pp,i);
> ```

You declared `make_pair` as a variable, hiding the function.

To fix this, get rid of your horrible macro definition.

Comment: yeah but it was giving output when placed outside the for loop, so I was confused.

Comment: @MrRobot9 It's not "outside the for loop" where it works, it's "outside the variable's scope". For instance, inside the loop but before the variable definition, it would also work.